# Como declarar parâmetros "nullable" em uma procedure Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Preciso que minha procedure aceite valores nulos em alguns parâmetros do tipo Number. Como faço isso no PL/SQL?

Atualmente:

```
PROCEDURE SP_EDITAR_QUADRO(
    P_IDQUADRO IN NUMBER,
    P_IDFUNC IN NUMBER,
    P_IDTRAB IN NUMBER
);
...
```

Preciso que o parâmetro `P_IDTRAB` aceite valores nulos.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso pelo operador `DEFAULT` ou `:=`

```
PROCEDURE ADD(aNUMBER, b NUMBER, c NUMBER DEFAULT 0)
```

Caso utilize pacotes com assinatura lembre-se de replicar o processo.

Se você quiser usá-lo sem nomeação explícita de parâmetros em chamadas, você deve colocar seus parâmetros opcionais no final da lista de assinaturas de procedimento.

[Leia Mais](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/fundamentals.htm#CHDFADII)

Comment: Resolvi deixando `P_IDTRAB IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: shoooooooowwww boa garoto. Se puder marcar como ✓